# ZF2 access to config in router configuration

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

i route by hostname and i want to get my domain name by local.php config file in config/autoload in `zf2`

i know how should i get configs in controller,
 but i dont know how can i get it in my router configuration file

i comment what i want in my code

```
  'router' => array(
             'routes' => array(

                 'advertise' => array(
                     'type'    => 'Hostname',
                     'options' => array(
                         'route' =>  'www.myhome.com', // here i want to get my domain by config 
                     'defaults'  => array(

                            'controller'    => 'Advertise\Controller\Advertise',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ), 
                    .............
```

Comment: why do you need your domain name in router?

Comment: require_once could be an easy solution :D

Comment: @MohamadMehdiHabibi because on my remote server i should change routename (hostname routing)  is require_once standard way of doing it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API of the 'router' service (an instance of `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack`) and [add a route dynamically](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#routing).

How you attach the route to the route stack is up to you, you could extend the default router factory `Zend\Mvc\Service\RouterFactory` with your own routes from config.

```
use MyModule\Mvc\Service;

use Zend\Mvc\Service\RouterFactory;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MyRouterFactory extends RouterFactory
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $cName = null, $rName = null)
    {
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

        $router = parent::createService($serviceLocator, $cName, $rName);
        $config = $serviceManager->get('config');

        $router->addRoute('advertise', [
            'type'    => 'hostname',
            'options' => [
                'route'    => $config['some_other_config_key'],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'Advertise\Controller\Advertise',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                ]
            ],
            'priority' => 123
        ]);

        return $router;
    }
}
```

Remember to register it with the name `Router` in `module.config.php` to replace the default implementation.

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Router' => 'MyModule\Mvc\Service\MyCustomRouterFactory',
    ],
],
```

The nice thing with this approach is that the routers construction is all kept in one place; also as you are adding it with a factory class
you have access to other services should you need them.

Alternatively, you could add it via an event, although being triggered via the event manager, this method would likely be more resource intensive.

```
namespace MyModule;

use Zend\ModuleManager\InitProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManagerInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\Application;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module implements InitProviderInterface
{
    // init is called when the module is initilised, we can use this to add a listener to the
    // 'bootstrap' event
    public function init(ModuleManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        $eventManager = $manager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

        $eventManager->attach(Application::class, MvcEvent::EVENT_BOOTSTRAP, [$this, 'addRoutes']);
    }

    public function addRoutes(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $router = $serviceManager->get('Router');
        $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');

        $router->addRoute('advertise', [
            'type'    => 'hostname',
            'options' => [
                'route'    => $config['some_other_config_key'],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'Advertise\Controller\Advertise',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                ]
            ],
            'priority' => 123
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: can i use a global varibale like $domainName and access it in my module.config.php instead of adding router?